# shutil.move PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, shutil

Hi i tried to move some local files to a nas but it raises an Access is denied error. I have compiled the script to .exe file with auto-py-to-exe. I tried to set some rights to the local folder but it didn't work. Run the script with adminrights but now i haven't rights on the nas, the rights on the nas i can't change.

python script:

```
import os, shutil, time, logging, stat

logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", format='%(asctime)s %(message)s\n', encoding='utf-8')

try:
    
    start = int(input("Startdate: "))
    end = int(input("Enddate: "))

    filePath = "D:/path/to/file"
    storePath = "Z:" 

    count= 0
    for file in os.listdir(filePath):
        fname = int(file.split("_")[0])

        if fname >= start and fname <= end:
            count += 1

    print(f"You are about to move {count} folder from {filePath} to {storePath}!")
    answer = input("Do you want to move these files?(y/n): ")


    if answer != "y":
        print("Cancelled!")
        exit()

    for file in os.listdir(filePath):
        fname = int(file.split("_")[0])

        if fname >= start and fname <= end:
            try:
                os.chmod(f"{filePath}/{file}", stat.S_IRWXU| stat.S_IRWXG| stat.S_IRWXO) # 0777
            except:
                logging.log(f"\nRights were not changed for\n{filePath}/{file}\n\n")
            shutil.move(f"{filePath}/{file}", f"{storePath}/{file}")
            print(f"{filePath}/{file} moved to {storePath}/{file}")
            time.sleep(60)

except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e, exc_info=True)
```

logfile:

```
2022-11-15 16:03:25,839 [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'D:/path/to/file/20211124_1_6377401797037988\\20211124.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shutil.py", line 824, in move
OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive: 'D:/path/to/file/20211124_1_6377401797037988' -> 'Z:/20211124_1_6377401797037988'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "shutil.py", line 842, in move
  File "shutil.py", line 758, in rmtree
  File "shutil.py", line 621, in _rmtree_unsafe
  File "shutil.py", line 619, in _rmtree_unsafe
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'D:/path/to/file/20211124_1_6377401797037988\\20211124.txt'
```

Comment: Is this the entire log? It looks like the log you show is the output from the outer `except`. Given this output, I'd expect something like "Rights were not changed for D:/path/to/file/20211124_1_6377401797037988\\20211124.txt" immediately before it. Regardless, it appears that this user doesn't have sufficient privilege to change the permissions on this file and then tries to move it, which generates the error in the question. Which user is trying to change permissions on the file, the owner?

Comment: @MichaelRuth Yes it is the entire log. It does not break off at the inner expect. I looked with which user the script runs and it was the "user1" which has administrative rights on the system, also I gave him the rights "full controll" for the folder.

Comment: Sorry for your time. i found the error, i give alle rights to dies folder but check for read only was checked. after uncheck this option i can move this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your path to file flips the '/' to '\' at the filename. You can use 'r' in front of file names to ensure the slashes are maintained
[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#:~:text=Both%20string%20and,is%20not%20supported](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#:%7E:text=Both%20string%20and,is%20not%20supported).

Comment: it dosnt matter if \ or / (i tryed)